# Create a graph / scheme with maths on Linux

Tags: math-software

i am having a really hard time trying to find a tool to create some easy scheme with mathematic formulas. 
Something as easy as that, for example:

[Simple Crypto scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOlIY.png)

I'm searching since some hours now and i still don't find what i want. Mathematica is really too complex for this task, xfig is really bad, AsciiMaths and others Latexlike are good for the equations but bad for the rest of the picture...

Basically, what i want is something as simple as a paint, but where i can write maths. I also want to be able to load a picture and add some text (maths equations) in it.

Please save me. I'm growing desperate.

Comment: It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but you should at least take a look at GeoGebra.

Comment: I know Geogebra. It's good to make graphs. But can you write mathematical expressions on an uploaded picture? Wait, i think i've done that already, a long time ago...So second point: is it available under Linux?

Comment: According to their [download page](https://www.geogebra.org/download?lang=en), it is available to Linux, yes (I also have it on my old Ubuntu laptop, I think it runs Ubuntu version 14.04, and if I recall correctly I installed Geogebra through the software center).

Comment: Inkscape may help you there. You can render latex formulas within the picture you draw and it is available for linux. Here is a link: https://inkscape.org/en/

Comment: So for geogebra: yeah, i found it and it works. However i can't find how to upload an image in it. Still think i done that already, but as said it was looong ago. 

For inkscape: i've got a look at it. It wasn't so easy to use. I was able to make a simple picture and use one already created, but not to add maths formulas where i want.

Comment: Edit: found out how to put the image in geogebra. Next step: put some maths on it.

Comment: The option in inkscape is a bit hidden. Under Extensions you find Render and under that should be latex somewhere. See https://jblevins.org/log/latex-in-inkscape for a more precise description.

Comment: Well, it would be good, but i don't have it. I only have a "Hershey Text". However, i found it in Geogebra. It was, in fact, pretty simple. And now i'm mad because i spend all the day looking for a tool i already knew ^^